# Adding labels for GCP App Engine Services

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, terraform

Any suggestion to manage `App Engine labels` using `gcloud` command or atleast from the `GCP console`. I am trying to add a `label` for an already deployed application

Cannot see any option to update `App Engine Service` label parameters with `gcloud` command

```
 $ gcloud app instances
 ERROR: (gcloud.app.instances) Command name argument expected.

 Available commands for gcloud app instances:

  delete                  Delete a specified instance.
  describe                Display all data about an existing instance.
  disable-debug           Disable debug mode for an instance.
  enable-debug            Enable debug mode for an instance (only works on
                          the flexible environment).
  list                    List the instances affiliated with the current App
                          Engine project.
  scp                     SCP from or to the VM of an App Engine Flexible
                          instance.
  ssh                     SSH into the VM of an App Engine Flexible
                          instance.
```

Also any option to manage from `terraform` ? .

Cannot find any `attributes` to manage `labels` anything under

```
 https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/app_engine_standard_app_version.html
 https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/app_engine_application.html
```

Comment: I tried a lot of stuff, impossible to find a public API for this. Even in the documentation, only the console is mentioned. No api for this :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although I couldn't find a way to do it through the gcloud CLI you can set labels to App Engine resources through the Console UI with the following steps:

1. Go to the App Engine Services page.
2. Mark the checkbox of the service you want to add labels to.
3. On the top right of the page, click on "Show Info Panel" and then labels.

This process is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/labeling-resources).

Moreover, feel free to file a feature requests in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) asking for the addition of a labeling option in the gcloud CLI.

Comment: Thanks so much . I will raise a feature request for this.

Answer (score 3):

Labels are now part of the API, but it does not look like it is documented. Using PATCH through the REST API can set labels on services for App Engine.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services/patch

The Service type does not include `labels`, but if you run `gcloud app services describe SERVICE --format=json`, you will see that labels is included in the response.

Example setting label using curl:

```
curl \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
      -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
      -X PATCH \
      -d '{"labels":{"label_name":"label_value"}}' \
     "https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/${project}/services/${service}?updateMask=labels"
```

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party but we needed to do something similar but using the C# AppEngine client library (Google.Apis.Appengine.v1). This works for us using the latest version of the library, assuming you've already retrieved the AppEngine service object, and you know your target projectId and service name:

```
var labels = new Dictionary<string,string>(); //Set your labels in here
service.Labels = labels;
var patchRequest = appEngineService.Apps.Services.Patch(service, project, 
serviceId);
patchRequest.UpdateMask = "Labels";
return await patchRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: Now the API is exposed I am looking forward to when terraform supports it.